# Como posso alterar o atributo de uma coluna com Laravel Migrations

Tags: laravel, migrations

Em meu banco de dados que criei usando as migrations do laravel possuo uma coluna chamada `celphone` que infelizmente não adicionei o atributo `->nullable()` quando a criei, agora que a base já esta em produção quero versionar essa alteração na tabela e adicionar a coluna como `nullable` para que não seja obrigatório popular esta informação.

Neste caso como fica a estrutura do método `up()` em uma migrations que modifica um atributo de coluna?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer uma alteração no campo, primeiramente adicione a depência  `doctrine/dbal` no seu composer.json e depois, você pode fazer a alteração dessa forma:

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('sexo')->nullable()->change();
});
```

traduzindo, se você cometeu um erro, crie uma nova migration e coloque a coluna que desaja alterar e especifique as alterações com o `->change()` no final, depois execute a migrate e a mágica acontece.

fonte: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#modifying-columns